# One to many Rails relationship. Is has_many required (Rails 5)?

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to generate a one-to-many relationship between users and advice. One user can have many advices.

```
rails g model User

rails g model Advice user:references
```

I noticed that this doesn't automatically generate the line `has_many :advices` in the user.rb file. However, in the advice.rb file, the line `belongs_to :user` was auto-generated.

In the rails console, I am still able to create multiple Advices for one user without an error.

My question is, is the `has_many :advices` line necessary in the user.rb file? If not, then why do the Rails guides recommend it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The has_many association tells Rails that the objects are related and adds methods to the object for querying the associated objects. You could live without it, but it makes things easier.

See the first chapter here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/association_basics.html

Another reference:
https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many

Answer (score 0):

When you use one-to-many associations you are telling your User model that he has zero or more instances of the model Advice, while Advice belongs to only one model User and its reference to it.

This is how your models should be:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord  
  has_many :advices
end

class Advice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Even if you don't need to declare it right now, you might need it in a long run, so it is always better to have it set. You can read more about this topic [here](https://kolosek.com/rkolosek.com/rails-associations/).